# MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: express, multipartform-data, react-redux

I'm trying to make a form with option for image upload. I'm using `express-http-proxy` as my API proxy and `multer` as suggested.

```
app.use('/api', upload.any(), proxy('http://localhost:3333'));
```

Issue is this error when submitting the form:

> Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START_BOUNDARY
>       at MultipartParser.end (/home/gabriel/Sites/city-amazing/api/node_modules/formidable/lib/multipart_parser.js:326:12)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/gabriel/Sites/city-amazing/api/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:130:30)
>       at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

How to handle any file upload using `express`?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yeah did you solve this? I have this problem as well

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error at my node + express back-end while accepting the image.

1. The first error I had was `weak header, multipart/form-data without boundary`.
2. Then after giving a boundary to it, I faced this same error `MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly`

I spent almost 5 hours debugging these errors and found out that don't give content-type header while sending your data. You may use other headers, but don't use `content-type: multipart/form-data` while sending formData to back-end.

This worked for me in my MERN project. It should work with other back-ends too.

Comment: So what content-type did you used?

Comment: @ArsalanAhmedQuershi I didnot use that header while sending the request. Just ignore that header.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I was trying to parse an image file from a form (multipart-form-data). The library I used for parsing is called ["formidable"](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/). So, i see that the same library is causing the error here as well.

The reason I got this error was because i set the encoding type for my request object this way `request.setEncoding("utf8");`. And then I was passing the request object to the parse method of formidable this way, `new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(request, callback);` This is what caused the error for me.

I simply removed the line `request.setEncoding("utf8");` and it started working.

Comment: I am having the same issue. But I don't explicitly set the setEncoding("utf8"). The same code works well on my Mac when I develop it. when I test it on nginX/ubuntu I get this error. Could you let me know if you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and fixed it by setting `parseReqBody: false`

```
app.use('/post', proxy('httpbin.org', {
  parseReqBody: false
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postman please uncheck the `content-type`